# Gerrit reports change-Id not found for earlier commits

Tags: git, gerrit

I am trying to setup gerrit code review for my existing GIT project.

The gerrit instance was running on my local on port **9090**.

Following is the process I followed

1. Create empty project in Gerrit (without initial commit). The name for the project was **SpringBootBasic**.
2. Cloned the remote git repo in some other location

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/hemantvsn/boot.git
   ```
3. Since gerrit needs Change-Id for each commit, copied the commit message hook into my cloned repository

   ```
   hemant:-~/Projects/boot$ scp -p -P 29418        
   hemantvsn@127.0.0.1:hooks/commit-msg .git/hooks/commit-msg                                                                                  
               100% 4693     3.4MB/s   00:00    
   hemant:-~/Projects/hem$
   ```
4. Added the a new remote to point to gerrit project

   ```
   hemant:-~/Projects/boot$ git remote add gerrit 
   http://127.0.0.1:9090/SpringBootBasic
   ```
5. Made a minor change and committed it.
   Change-Id was populated in this commit.

   ```
   hemant:-~/Projects/boot$ git log
   --------------------------------
   commit 98f1c6534492984364bdbc714407dbb8b39c06da
   Author: hemant <hemantvsn@gmail.com>
   Date:   Wed Apr 12 14:43:42 2017 +0530

   Minor text changes.

   Change-Id: I48e625c728add8be45b4dee0809c1d0d9804b7c8

   --------------------------------

   commit 5d485988e6d67394622bbd5d2d3146fc379b7ec3
   Author: hemant <hemantvsn@gmail.com>
   Date:   Wed Apr 5 13:22:09 2017 +0530

   Added sysouts
   --------------------------------

   commit 330c5c6ca2fed898146efe81f99b4ee91faa614f
   Author: hemant <hemantvsn@gmail.com>
   Date:   Wed Apr 5 13:03:40 2017 +0530

   changed index file
   --------------------------------
   ```
6. Finally when Im tring to push my changes to the gerrit report, its still 
   showing error as change-Id not populated in commit.

   ```
    hemant:-~/Projects/boot$ git push gerrit HEAD:refs/for/master
    Counting objects: 43, done.
    Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
    Compressing objects: 100% (29/29), done.
    Writing objects: 100% (43/43), 4.29 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
    Total 43 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)
    remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (6/6)
    remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done    
    remote: ERROR: [f905e04] missing Change-Id in commit message 
    footer
    remote: 
    remote: Hint: To automatically insert Change-Id, install the hook:
    remote:   gitdir=$(git rev-parse --git-dir); scp -p -P 29418 
    hemantvsn@127.0.0.1:hooks/commit-msg ${gitdir}/hooks/
    remote: And then amend the commit:
    remote:   git commit --amend
    remote: 
    To http://127.0.0.1:9090/SpringBootBasic
    ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/master ([f905e04] missing 
    Change-Id in commit message footer)
    error: failed to push some refs to 
    'http://127.0.0.1:9090/SpringBootBasic'


    hemant:-~/Projects/boot$
   ```

It seems that its referring to my initial commits in repo, which were done before gerrit.

```
 hemant:-~/Projects/boot$ git log --pretty=format:'%h %ad %s (%an)' --date=short 
98f1c65 2017-04-12 Minor text changes. (hemantvsn)
5d48598 2017-04-05 Added sysouts (hemant)
330c5c6 2017-04-05 changed index file (hemant)
90bb7be 2017-04-05 sonar file (hemant)
eca2fc2 2017-03-30 test (hemant)
f905e04 2017-02-03 Basic Spring Boot Project. (hemantvsn) **** This commit is referred in error report.
```

Please suggest what needs to be done
Also Please suggest any changes in config.

Comment: `f905e04` is not visible in your `git log`. Where this sha came from? Where does it point to?

Comment: Its my initial commit in the remote git repo (f905e04 2017-02-03 Basic Spring Boot Project. (hemantvsn))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the Change-Id in ALL commits of your repository, you just added it in the last one.

The correct way to push a new repository to Gerrit is to push straight to the branch (git push gerrit HEAD:refs/**heads**/master) but you need to have permission to do that. Ask for your Gerrit administrator.